# How to grep the difference between two files into a file

Tags: sed, grep, regular-expression, tcl

Saying that I have two files: a.txt and b.txt.

The content of a.txt:

```
mosfet23
cap098
inductors 98
metal96
```

The content of b.txt:

```
test 23 cap098
drc45 metal96
lvs cap098
```

Of course I can use vimdiff to check their difference

My question is how to record devices which exists in a.txt but doesn't exist in b.txt into a file?

also we cant use comm as b.txt is not sorted?

How to achieve using tcl,grep or sed?

Comment: you have an unclarified still open question here [For every string in file1.txt check if it exists in file2.txt then do something](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/690727/for-every-string-in-file1-txt-check-if-it-exists-in-file2-txt-then-do-something)

Comment: i think its now remove some clouds ..fresh question

Comment: so you expect us we should restart asking the same clarification here?! or how this question is different from the previous one?

Comment: Your sample data is unclear: is "metal96" in b.txt? Is whitespace supposed to be ignored?

Comment: "_can't use `comm` as `b.txt` is not sorted_" is there any reason why it shouldn't be sorted?

Answer (score 0):

Answer using Bash:

```
comm -2 -3 \
  <(xargs -n 1 < a.txt | sort) \
  <(xargs -n 1 < b.txt | sort) > foo.txt
```

`xargs -n 1` output string split by a newline.
You can use `comm` command and "Process Substitution" of Bash. `<(...)` is the result of `...` as like file. Finally, you can use the redirection symbol to write the result to a file like `foo.txt`.